# What is the difference between uneval() and .toSource()

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `uneval(...)` and `.toSource()`?

> The toSource() method returns a string representing the source code of the object.
>
> The uneval() method creates an string representation of the source code of an Object.

Comment: yes, their output is the same ... but are you sure it will be same for __any__ object? If uneval is only the alias for .toSource why not to say this explicitly in MDN article?

Comment: Noone said it is an alias. Almost everything in javascript is an object.

Answer (score 2):

One takes a param, the other doesn't. That appears to be the only difference, although the use of both is discouraged.

```
uneval(object);

Object.toSource();
obj.toSource();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/uneval
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource

**Straight from those sites above:**

> Non-standard
>
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

I'd stay away from this feature. There's likely a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`uneval()` is a method you can pass a piece of javascript to.
`.toSource()` is an extension method for objects.

Both functions output the same shown in the following example:

```
var a = 1234;
console.log(uneval(a)); //outputs "1234"
console.log(a.toSource()); //outputs "1234"
```

Comment: let equal=true; for(let a of possibleObjects) if(a.toSource()!==uneval(a)){ equal=false; break; }

Answer (score 0):

*Be aware: Both, `toSource` and `uneval`, are proprietary non-standard features.*

While `uneval` is a function, i.e. a `window` method independend from the subject, `toSource` is implemented as a method of the subject. Due to this fact, additional error handling needs to be done when using `toSource`. On the other hand, `uneval` is capable to handle variables not being initialized with an actual object.

```js
for(let v of [null, undefined])
{
  console.log(uneval(v));

  try
  {
    console.log(v.toSource());
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```